# Does a game recommendation website exist?

Tags: recommendations

Is there a website that will collect your evaluations of various board games that you've played and will then recommend a board game that you will like, based on your evaluations and on those of other members?

Comment: I think you should post this on [Meta B&CG instead](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) as this site is not for game recommendations (nor is your question asking about games, is asking about sites). [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) could also be a place to ask this I think... (or you could ask the folks there for their recommendations :)

Comment: Ah, but they're not asking for game recommendations - they're asking for a site that recommends games.  That's very different.  Would a question about BGG be on topic?

Comment: This question does not belong on meta. It's not a question about the B&CG site itself. It's *also* not a question asking for game recommendations, and the reasons for deeming those questions off-topic (see [https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/409]) don't apply here, so I'm reopening it. If y'all still think it's off-topic, feel free to discuss on [meta] and if appropriate vote to close here. But bottom line: meta isn't a place to stick possibly off-topic or out-of-scope questions that we want to answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Board Game Finder ( https://www.boardgamefinder.net/ ) does exactly that.

From the "How It Works" section of that site:

> To provide the boardgame recommendations, we focus on collaborative filtering. In collaborative filtering, we have a set of items (boardgames) that have been rated by users. The main idea of collaborative filtering is to infer the preferences of each user based not only on the ratings provided by that user, but also on the ratings of all other users in the system. These preferences are then used to form the actual predictions. Thus, collaborative filtering makes use of the ratings of all users to make predictions about a given user. In other words, it recommends items that other users with preferences similar to yours rated positively. This is why it is called collaborative.